# PHP - Encoding strikes again

Tags: php, html, ajax, postgresql, utf-8

I'm having encoding problems in my webpage, and it is driving me crazy. Let me try to explain

- I have a meta tag defining utf8 as charset.
- I'm including the scripts as utf8 too (`<script type="text/javascript src="..." charset="utf8"></script>`).
- In .php files, I declare `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');`
- In my database (postgreSQL), I've made the query `show lc_collate;` and the return was `en_US.UTF-8`
- I'm using AJAX
- When I try to save the field value "name" as "áéíóú", I get the value "Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº" in the record set (using phpPgAdmin to view results).

What am I doing wrong? There's a way to fix it without using decode/encode? Someone have a good reference about theses issues?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can i view query which store data?

Comment: The query is: 'update {$this->tabela_bd} set senha = ?, saudacao = ?, mail = ? where id = ?;"' . I'm using prepared statements.

Comment: i think you may set query encoding

Comment: Please post the output of the SQL statements "show server_encoding" and "show client_encoding".  To be complete, I would suggest posting the output of these commands from three environments:  inside your PHP/JS application, from phpPGAdmin, and from a command-line connection to the db using psql.  If any of those do not read at UTF-8, then that should shed some light on your issue.

Comment: IS your phpPgAdmin configured correctly? What does psql say? If you don't have shell access, upload a script which fetches the data and displays it to see if the data is actually saved as UTF-8 and phpPgAdmin is configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the client encoding is not set correctly? PostgreSQL automatically converts between the character encoding on the client and the encoding in the database. For this to work it needs to know what encoding the client is using. Safest is to set this when you open your connection using:

SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';

For details [see the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might be storing the data as ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I can't change the bd tables collate. I've tried to change the encoding of my .html, .js and .php files to iso-8859-1, but it only makes another set of weird chars updated in bd.

Answer (score 0):

Try enconding to base64 and decoding on the other end.